# C++ access multiple members by array

Tags: c++

Lot's of year from last project in C++, I cannot remember/find how to do this.

Sample (pseudo code) :

```
    MyClass
    {
    public :
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    }

    main.cpp

    void MyFunction(void)
    {
        MyClass *myclass = new MyClass(); 
        float x = myclass->x;

        //want I want :
        float *xyz = myclass->xyz;
    }
```

How to do this ?

Thank you very much and sorry for my poor english.

[EDITED]
It's only a concept now, but the goal, is near the vec4 class in GLSL (OpenGL Shader for GPU). Vec4 is a math vector class with four values (x, y, z, w). You can get/assign value like this sample :

```
vec4 vectorA = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
vectorA.x = 2.0;
vec2 vectorB = vectorA.xy;
vec3 vectorC = vectorA.xxx;
```

etc. (so : VectorC.x = 2.0, vectorC.y = 2.0, vectorC.z = 2.0)

Comment: Um... What's `xyz` supposed to be?

Comment: An array containing [0] = x, [1] = y, [2] = z

Comment: Also see http://glm.g-truc.net/ (OpenGL Mathematics) to see how they do swizzling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [unnamed structure](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html):

```
union Vector
{
    struct 
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    };
    float xyz[3];
};
```

Then you can access components without implicitly referencing containing structure:

```
int main()
{ 
    Vector* vec = new Vector();
    vec->x = 50;
    vec->y = 30;
    vec->xyz[2] = vec->xyz[0] + vec->xyz[1]; // vec->z == 80
    delete vec;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you can wrap this union with another structure/class, to same effect:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    union
    {
        struct 
        {
            float x;
            float y;
            float z;
        };
        float xyz[3];
    };
};
```

Also, why create your structure on heap (using "new")? Won't allocating on stack do?

EDIT: Oh, I get it. Well, it's definitely doable, but it is worth it *only* if you want as much compability with GLSL as possible. The idea is to create a "proxy" that stores references for each component variation. The tradeof is that vec2, instead of taking 8 bytes of memory will take 40 bytes. It will obviously get much, much worse for vec3 & vec4

```
class vec2
{
    // private proxy, auto-convertible into vec2
    struct proxy2
    {
        // store references, not values!
        proxy2(float &x, float &y) : x(x), y(y) {}
        // implicit conversion to vec2
        operator vec2() { return vec2(x, y); }
        // support assignments from vec2
        proxy2& operator=(const vec2& vec) 
        { 
            x = vec.x; 
            y = vec.y; 
            return *this; 
        }
    private:
        // hide copy and assignment operators
        proxy2(const proxy2&);
        proxy2& operator=(const proxy2&);
        // hide member variables
        float& x;
        float& y;
    };

public:
    vec2(float _x, float _y) 
        : x(_x), y(_y) 
        , xx(x, x), xy(x, y), yx(y, x), yy(y, y)
    {}

    vec2(const vec2& vec)
        : x(vec.x), y(vec.y)
        , xx(x, x), xy(x, y), yx(y, x) , yy(y, y)
    {}

    float x;
    float y;
    proxy2 xx;
    proxy2 xy;
    proxy2 yx;
    proxy2 yy;
};
```

With this class you can get syntax pretty close to what GLSL offers:

```
vec2 v(1.0f, 2.0f);
vec2 vxx = v.xx; // 1, 1
vec2 vyx = v.yx; // 2, 1
vec2 vxy = v.xy; // 1, 2
vec2 vyy = v.yy; // 2, 2

v.yx = vec2(3, 4); // 4, 3
v.y = 5;           // 4, 5

vec2::proxy2 proxy = v.xx;     // compile error
v.xx = vec2::proxy2(v.x, v.y); // compile error
```

To extend this to support `vec3` and `vec4` simply derive from `vec2` and `vec3` respectively, create `proxy3` and `proxy4` structs and declare member for each component variation (27 for `vec3` and mere 64 for `vec4`).

EDIT2: New version, that does not take extra space at all. Again, unions to the rescue! Converting `proxy2` to a template and adding data member that matches `vec2` components you can safely put it into an union.

```
class vec2
{
    // private proxy, auto-convertible into vec2
    template <int x, int y>
    struct proxy2
    {
        // implicit conversion to vec2
        operator vec2()
        { 
            return vec2(arr[x], arr[y]); 
        }
        // support assignments from vec2
        proxy2& operator=(const vec2& vec) 
        { 
            arr[x] = vec.x; 
            arr[y] = vec.y; 
            return *this; 
        }
    private:
        float arr[2];
    };

public:
    vec2(float _x, float _y) 
        : x(_x), y(_y) 
    {}

    vec2(const vec2& vec)
        : x(vec.x), y(vec.y)
    {}

    union
    {
        struct 
        {
            float x;
            float y;
        };
        proxy2<0, 0> xx;
        proxy2<0, 1> xy;
        proxy2<1, 0> yx;
        proxy2<1, 1> yy;
    };
};
```

Hope this is what you are after.

EDIT3: I took me a while, but I came up with [a working GLSL emulation library](https://github.com/gwiazdorrr/CxxSwizzle) (includes swizzling) allowing you to run fragment shaders *without modifications*. If you are still interested, you should take a look.

Comment: Thank you, it's close for what I want, but not exactly. How to get vec->xxx or other ?

Comment: I wouldn't have them as members but construct them when needed. It will mean you have to use brackets to access the swizzled versions.

Comment: @chrisendymion: I thought you wanted to keep as close as possible to GLSL?

Comment: Wow, what a great answer, thank you so much for you help and for your time !! Yes, it's exactly what I wanted ;)

Comment: This is a nice pile of UB in C++03. Might be better-defined in C++11 but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes, it's probably true. Could you, by any chance, list some? I think that well placed static assertions could detect any problems, though.

Answer (score 3):

C++ can accommodate syntax like `vec.xyx`, but it's not easy to write. And you won't get there by adding features one by one. It's better to list the requirements, select the tools, and make a straight shot.

What you need:

1. A storage class like `std::array`
2. Members named `x`, `y`, … `xy`, `xz`, … `xyz`, `xzx`, …
3. Something that converts those members to the desired output
4. Types to give the output the desired semantics

The first requirement is simple: use `std::array`.

Next you have to define 3 + 3^2 + 3^3 = 39 members. This can be done by copy-paste but you're better off with template metaprogramming. With a `z` member it's a must.

The types of the members are meaningless, but must tell the compiler how to choose the named elements from the array.

Example:

```
selection_vector< 0, 1, 0 > xyx;
selection_vector< 0, 1, 1 > xyy; // ad nauseam
```

Ideally these members would know how to select the elements with no state, but they will need to be initialized with `this` and take up one pointer each. So be aware that each 3-vector object wastes 312 bytes.

To make the members do something, you have to define conversion functions. So you have something like

```
selection_vector::operator array3_type() { return { ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2] }; }
```

Implicit conversion functions apply when performing assignment and passing as a function argument besides `this`, but not in many other situations. So to obtain `vec.xyx.x` or `vec.xyx[ 1 ]` the `selection_vector` type would need to define additional members.

Once you've defined the web of crazy types and operator overloads, you'll be able to save a few keystrokes…

### Minor compromise

It sounds like you don't really want to compromise, but the `->*` operator is worth mentioning. It's the best non-member operator overload for implementing subscripts.

This allows a pattern like

```
xyx_type xyx;

template< typename vec >
my_3vector< vec > operator->* ( vec &&v, xyx_type )
    { return { v[0], v[1], v[2] }; }

std::array< float, 3 > a { 0.5, 1.5, 9 };

my_3vector< … > b = a->*xyx;
```

You could even make `my_3vector` simply `std::array` and avoid any template metaprogramming. Make `xyx_type` an enumeration to avoid preprocessor metaprogramming too.

The `->*` operator stands in for `.`. This makes things a lot easier, but note that `->*` has funny precedence; it's lower than `.` and `->` whereas you would expect it to be a peer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time ! If I could, I would choose both your answer and giazdorrr's answer as valid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution possible, a slight variation to union-based example posted by @gwiazdorrr. It assumes

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

struct MyClass
{
    enum { size = 3 };

    typedef float& reference;
    reference x;
    reference y;
    reference z;

    MyClass() 
        : x(xyz[0] = 0), y(xyz[1] = 0), z(xyz[2] = 0)
    {}
    MyClass(float x, float y, float z)
        : x(xyz[0] = x), y(xyz[1] = y), z(xyz[2] = z)
    {}
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass const& other)
    {
        std::copy(other.xyz, other.xyz + size, xyz);
        return *this;
    }

    // convenient indexed access
    reference operator[](std::size_t index)
    {
        if (index < size)
            return xyz[index];
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("index not less than size");
    }

    // raw data access
    float* data() { return xyz; }

private:
    float xyz[size];
};

int main()
{
    MyClass c1;
    MyClass c2(1, 2, 3);
    c1 = c2;
    assert(c1.data()[0] == c2[0]);
    assert(c1.data()[1] == c2[1]);
    assert(c1.data()[2] == c2[2]);

    MyClass c3(c2);
    assert(c2[0] == c3.x);
    assert(c2[1] == c3.y);
    assert(c2[2] == c3.z);
}
```

I assumed no access to C++11, thus the initialisation gymnastics in the constructors.